# php does not send mail to recipients

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, implode

i got a php script which should send a mail to multiple recipients. I want to write all recipients to BCC. The email adresses are retrieved from a mysql database. Unfortunately it won't send any mails.

Here is the script:

```
    <?php
include("/path/to/config.php"); 
$db = @new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die ('Konnte keine Verbindung zur Datenbank aufbauen: '.mysqli_connect_error().'('.mysqli_connect_errno().')');
}

$sql = "select email from newsletter";
$recipients = array();
$result = $db->query($sql);     

if (!$result) {
  printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
  exit;
}      
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   $recipients[]=$row;
}

print_r($recipients);

$result->close();
$db->close();


$to = 'myemail';
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$body = $_POST["message"];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: support@mymail.de' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: ' . implode(', ', $recipients) . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

print_r returns a valid response:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => first@mail.com ) [1] => Array ( [0] => second@mail.com ) )
```

Comment: What does the call to `mail` return?

Comment: Basic debugging would have made the problem obvious. What does `echo $headers` display?

Comment: be careful with BCC there may be a limit, depending on the mail server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making an array of arrays:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
      ^^^^---array
   $recipients[]=$row;
                 ^^^^---add array to another array
}
```

You probably want something like

```
while($row = ...) {
  $recipients[] = $row[0];
}
```

so you're adding JUST the email addresses.

Since you're imploding your array-of-arrays, and stuffing the resulting string into another string, you're going to literally get `BCC: Array, Array, Array, ....`

Comment: Thanks that did it. I can accept only in about 5 minutes. Thanks ;)